# how to listen and accept BluetoothSocket in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, spp

I am developing a Bluetooth SPP program in Samsung GT-P7500 android Pad.I want to receives SPP connection from peer BT device. I tried the API method:

```
public BluetoothServerSocket listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(String name, UUID uuid);
public BluetoothServerSocket listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(String name, UUID uuid);
```

and also I tried `listenUsingRfcommOn(int)` by reflection method.All above did not success.
I have tried my program in other android device, Sony Ericsson X10i, Galaxy 9100, It is OK on those  devices.
Anyone has experiences in Android Bluetooth development and  experiences on GT-P7500?
Tanks for any suggestions!

Comment: What UUID of a service have you provided? Perhaps, such service isn't supported on GT-P7500?

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the example "BluetoothChat" codes, it's very useful.
Here is the link: http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html, and you can download source code from SVN server or you can search on internet for the source code.